# Google Search Console fetch and render says CSS, fonts and images are "Temporarily unreachable"

Tags: seo, google-search-console, css, images, fetch-as-google

I have requested that Google index (Fetch and render in Search Console) my website on 4th August 2018 but still it didn't get indexed and it is stating that some scripts, style sheets, fonts and images can’t be reached temporarily. Can anyone give me solution on how to solve this issue?

[image]